# Javascript Image Overlay not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a website page that I am trying to get secondary images to overlay a primary image on mouseover or click.  The image overlay action is triggered by hotspots on the primary image. The code works within Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera, but not IE?  Does anyone know a way to correct it for IE?

Webpage: http://www.neurobalancingcenter.com

**Style Code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.imgoverlay 
{
position:absolute;
margin: 10px 0 0 487px;
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jkimagelarge').hover(
       function () {
           $('.pic').prepend('<div class="imgoverlay"><img src="' + $(this).attr('pic') + '" /></div>');
       },
       function () {
           $('.imgoverlay').each(function () { $(this).hide(); });
       }
    );
});

</script>
```

**Body code:**

```
<div class="pic">
<map id="FPMap0" name="FPMap0">
<area coords="508, 227, 738, 252" href="#" pic="/images/what_is_bwo.jpg" shape="rect" class="jkimagelarge" />
<area coords="508, 252, 726, 279" href="#" pic="/images/why_bwo.jpg" shape="rect" class="jkimagelarge" />
<area coords="508, 279, 667, 300" href="#" pic="/images/how_bwo.jpg" shape="rect" class="jkimagelarge" />
</map>
<img src="images/homepage_a_focused_mind.jpg" alt="" title="" usemap="#FPMap0" />
</div>
```

Comment: you dont need image map for this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you aren't just using a :hover selector and swapping the image out that way using background-image? Then you don't need the image map at all.

Comment: In your code every time you hover, you're adding new elements to the `DOM`, and never removing them, so more and more are added each time.

Comment: which IE version(s)? What rendering mode is IE using? And what jQuery version are you using? Are there any errors in the IE console?

Answer (score 0):

Now this is not a silver plate but some food for thought, you should be able to fix your problem with this technique:

http://jsbin.com/aqobuj/1/edit

```
a {
  display:block;
  border:solid;
}
div {
  border:solid;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
}
a.one:hover ~ div#one {
  display:block;
}
a.two:hover ~ div#two {
  display:block;
}
a.three:hover ~ div#three {
  display:block;
}
```

Techniques used:

- hover css pseudoselector
- display:block/none (css's hide/show)
- tilde/sibling selector (give me the next div with class x in this case)